# How does Nature's Fury work?

Tags: diablo-iv

Nature's Fury is a Druid skill which reads as follows:

> Casting an Earth skill has a 20% chance to trigger a free Storm skill of the same category.
>
> In addition, casting a Storm skill has a 20% chance to trigger a free
> Earth skill of the same category.

That's pretty handy, but also a little vague. Specifically, what I'm wondering is:

- **Investment Required:** Will this only trigger skills I've invested points into?
- **Skill Level:** What skill level will the triggered skills be cast at?
- **Skill Passives:** Will any passive abilities be applied to the triggered skills?

In other words, I'm looking for a fairly good overview of what the properties of the triggered skills will be.

Comment: I fully expect this to be a tricky one to answer, and it'll require a decent amount of research and testing, so I plan to add a bounty once the question is eligible for one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the talent tree, each "cluster" is labeled for the classes.

For druid, these clusters are

- *Basic*
- *Core*
- *Defensive*
- *Companion*
- *Wrath*
- *Ultimate*

Each one of the clusters has an associated skill set to choose to spend your ability points. The skills have associated magic types. Storm and Earth are magic types.

So, when you have this description:

> Casting an Earth skill has a 20% chance to trigger a free Storm skill of the same category.

> In addition, casting a Storm skill has a 20% chance to trigger a free Earth skill of the same category.

It really means (translated):

> Using a skill whose magic type is Earth has a 20% chance to then use a skill in the same cluster whose magic type is Storm (regardless of if there are points there).

> And vice versa.

Okay, words, am I right? Perhaps if you are reading this it still seems kinda hand wavey. Here is an example (assuming no modifications to spell types):

**Earth**

If you use [] then it has a 20% chance to cast []:

- *Basic*
  Earthspike -> Storm Strike
- *Core*
  Landslide -> Tornado *or* Lightning Storm (random chance)
- *Defensive*
  Earthen Bulwark -> Cyclone Armor
- *Wrath*
  Boulder -> Hurricane

*And vice versa*

**Storm**

If you use [] then it has a 20% chance to cast []:

- *Basic*
  Storm Strike -> Earthspike
- *Core*
  Tornado -> Landslide
  Lightning Storm -> Landslide
- *Defensive*
  Cyclone Armor -> Earthen Bulwark
- *Wrath*
  Hurricane -> Boulder

---

You can read up on the descriptions of the skills here: https://diablo4.purediablo.com/Druid_Skill_Tree

---

With regards to the skill level and application of passives, casting and triggering are two different uses. When a skill is triggered, it comes as its level 1 form only, and does not benefit from passives.

Comment: Spirit should actually be Core here. There is not tag for Spirit it's just the resource.

A sidenote is that there are aspects that change properties of skills. For example there is an aspect called Ursine Horror that makes Pulverize (Core skill) also counting as earth. Meaning it will be part of the potential casts from the Core category.

Comment: `With regards to the skill level and application of passives, these will be applied as if you were normally casting the skill. If you have it locked, it will cast the skill at level 1.` Did you confirm this via in-game testing?

Comment: @Wipqozn - I had tested only at low level. On further testing it appears that this does slightly deviate from prior versions of the game, in that it does not seem to apply the passive or leveled benefits.

Comment: @trappski - Yes, you are correct thank you.

Comment: @TravisJ Okay, I see you've changed your answer. Did you originally test this during the beta, then upon retesting now realized there was a change?

Comment: @Wipqozn - I have extensively played the Diablo series and would consider myself highly knowledgeable on game mechanics in that space. Generally they do keep mechanics somewhat consistent across different game versions. As a result I tested this at a lower level than had access to some passives and casts and did not realize that they were not being applied during testing. It was done during the pre release, current production, of the game. After writing this though, I realized during gameplay that the mechanic was slightly different for the nuance of cast versus trigger and came back to edit.